# the videos that I recorded on my Canon DSLR are nowhere to be found

Tags: canon, dslr, video

my canon DSLR stopped recording videos automatically then I deleted some videos and continued again but when I inserted my SD card to my laptop the videos are nowhere to be found. Are those videos somehow saved? if yes how can I access them? thanks

Comment: Did the camera stop recording because it was out of space? Why did you delete those videos?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to recover the videos you deleted or do you mean that the files you recorded after deleting videos are not found either?  Is there any other data visible on the card?  Can you play back the videos on the camera?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, even deleted files are still on the disk until they are over written by some other file. Try running file recovery software such as Recuva or Puran. Be sure to read the software user guides before starting.
However, I once got caught out looking for files on a card when the device was actually saving to it's built in storage. I am not aware of any canon DSLR with built in storage though.

Comment: I deleted it because the it said stopped recording videos automatically. thanks. ill give it a try. :-)